# Filtering array of objects against another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
customerProducts: [
  {
    name: "foo",
    id: 123
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    id: 44
  }
]

otherProducts: [
  {
    name: "other",
    id: 44
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    id: 21
  }
]
```

I want to iterate through `customerProducts`, which is an array of objects.  I want to filter the `customerProducts` that have an ID that another array of objects, `otherProducts`, has.  So for examople, I'd want the returned result in this case to be:

```
  {
    name: "test",
    id: 44
  }
```

since `otherProducts` has an `id` of 44.

I was thinking of mapping through `otherProducts` and just returning an array of IDs, then running a `forEach` on that but that seems like a long way of doing it.

Comment: Make an array of all the IDs in `otherProducts`. Then filter `customerProducts` using a callback function that uses `otherIds.includes(product.id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an indexed [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the values to filter by (`id` from `otherProducts`) then filter `customerProducts` by that Set

```js
const customerProducts = [{name: "foo",id: 123},{name: "test",id: 44}]

const otherProducts = [{name: "other",id: 44},{name: "test",id: 21}]

const otherProductIds = new Set(otherProducts.map(({ id }) => id))

const filteredCustomerProducts = customerProducts.filter(({ id }) => 
  otherProductIds.has(id))
  
console.info(filteredCustomerProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `customerProducts` , `otherProducts` as JS array variable and use JS Array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) functions

```
let customerProducts = [
  {
    name: "foo",
    id: 123
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    id: 44
  }
]

let otherProducts = [
  {
    name: "other",
    id: 44
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    id: 21
  }
];

let filtered = customerProducts.filter( el => otherProducts.find( e => e.id == el.id) )

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using array methods [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
customerProducts.filter((x)=> otherProducts.some(y=> y.id === x.id));
```

Explanation:
filter method will call each and every element in the `otherProducts` array and check if the `id` of `customerProduct` is present in `otherProducts` for at least one element.